# Access variable outside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to put the content of a file in an array. But when I try to access the variable `fileArray` it is empty after `lineReader.on`. This the code:

```
var fileArray=[]

    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: require('fs').createReadStream('file-to-read')  
    });

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  fileArray.push(line)
  //console.log(fileArray)  
});
// I want to get the array here but it is currently empty
console.log(fileArray)
```

Thanks

Comment: it is due to async nature of function, outside `console.log` runs before file is read that's why its empty

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon, if that's true then writing the function in an IIFE would make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `lineReader.on('line', function () {})` is an event handler - i.e. the function you pass to it gets called asynchronously when the event takes place. However, this doesn't stop the rest of your code from executing - immediately after you define your lineReader event handler, the next line executes, before anything has been added to the array. To get the result you're after, your final `console.log` needs to be in a `'close'` event handler - this will get called when the input stream hits the end.